# Install-Package & NuGet Package install location - where installed to?

Tags: powershell, nuget, installation, powershell-module

```
> nuget                                                                                                         
nuget : The term 'nuget' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. ...

> find-package -name nuget | Install-package -verbose
VERBOSE: Skipping installed package NuGet 1.3.3.

> nuget                                                                                                         
nuget : The term 'nuget' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. ...
```

If it is installed, where is it installed?  I searched across the drive and no other copies of `nuget.exe` exist except for the one I manually installed (but which is obviously not in the $PATH so surely it is not referring to that - I renamed it to double-check!).

---

#### Question update

I had an expectation from my Java experience and it seems like I was asking the wrong question.

My use case is below.  Background first.

- I am new to MS App development though have a decade of Java dev experience.
- (Where i currently are) there is an old version of ASP.Net application that won't work with the `dotnet` cli.
- The team here had hard coded (saved) dependencies and also created their build system to expect to find other dependencies such as in a Visual Studio install.  Having my background I don't like this expectation, especially when it comes to scaling.
- The existing build system uses `MSBuild` and makes use of `.targets` files

My use case is to run a build using defined (NOT PRE-DOWNLOADED) dependencies and on a server that has no expectation about the build environment apart from some key tools.  Visual Studio is an IDE and I don't expect to find this on a server.

I have created dependencies in a `packages.config` file.  I want to add `nuget.exe` to the build script (currently a `build.bat` but a powershell equivalent is preferred).

I know there is a lot of information out there, but with my lack of knowledge in this area tied to the fact that what I want to do is rooted somewhere around 2012 (I'm guessing), I'm not sure what to do.

Given what I do know, I thought all I wanted to do is:

1. Install `nuget` at the start of the `build.bat / build.ps1` script
2. Run `nuget` to install the defined dependencies

   - I have downloaded `nuget` manually, run `nuget restore` and confirmed that it does what I want
3. Run the build as before

The first attempt at asking this question was to address #1 from this list.  I thought powershell could be used to download `nuget.exe` and then the build script could call `nuget restore`.

Comment: You are right.  Thanks for reading and answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it is installed, where is it installed?

Assuming you are on a Windows machine, PowerShell packages are usually installed in `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` (global) or `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` (CurrentUser).

nuget.exe specifically is installed - yeah, just where you install it; quoting from [NuGet CLI Reference (MSDocs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference):

> ### Installing nuget.exe
>
> 1. On Mac and Linux, install Mono 4.4.2 or later.
> 2. Visit nuget.org/downloads and select the version of NuGet you want.
> 3. **Each download is the `nuget.exe` file directly. Instruct your browser to save the file to a folder of your choice. The file is not an installer; running it from the browser won't show anything.**
> 4. Add the folder where you placed `nuget.exe` to your PATH environment variable to use the CLI tool from anywhere.

This seems somewhat confusing, doesn't it? Keep in mind that there are 3 different packages/applications:

1. [NuGet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference) (like referenced)
2. [NuGet PowerShell Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/powershell-reference) / Package Manager Console (What you are searching for I think) exports own [`Install-Package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/ps-ref-install-package)
3. PowerShell's [PackageManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/?view=powershell-5.1) Package (Which also an [`Install-Package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/Install-Package?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet)

Comment: Thanks @Clijsters I think I had an expectation based upon previous experiences (I come from the Java world) and asked the wrong question.  I will update my question.  I want the CLI version so our build script can install dependencies.

Comment: I think the easiest way to do so is an install script starting with `iwr "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe" "$pwd/nuget.exe"`
Keep in mind that the target machines must have the correct Execution Policy to run PoSh scripts.

Comment: Great, I'll try that out.

Comment: I had to use `iwr <uri> -o $pwd\nuget.exe` (or `wget  <uri> -o $pwd\nuget.exe` or `curl ...`).  Or use `-OutFile` instead of `-o`.

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading my updated question, I don't think it is an issue to install `nuget.exe` on the build servers.  Or use docker eg. https://blog.alexellis.io/3-steps-to-msbuild-with-docker/.

As @Clijsters rightly pointed out, there are instructions on downloading `nuget`.  And this would be the most sensible thing to do.  I was just a bit confused with the ability for power shell to install it.  But that is not `nuget.exe`.

The environment I'm working in likely doesn't support Docker so I won't pursue that at this time.